# Почему задержка при отрисовке линий?

Tags: ipad, ios

Помогите решить проблему с запаздывающей отрисовкой линий в простой рисовалке для iPad, вот код:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"Начали");
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    mouseSwiped = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [self.mainDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    self.mainDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self.mainDrawImage setAlpha:opacity];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    lastPoint = currentPoint;

    NSLog(@"Двигаем");
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if(!mouseSwiped) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [self.mainDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, opacity);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        self.mainDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainDrawImage.frame.size);
    [self.mainDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    self.mainDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSLog(@"Конец");
}
```

При движении пальцем по экрану, отрисовка линии запаздывает тестирую на iPad2. Как решить проблему?

Comment: попробуйте перерисовывать не в каждом mousemove,  а хотя бы через раз или два. А во вторых, рисовать нужно в отдельных методах типа onDraw (не знаю, как он в iOS называется).

Comment: Спасибо за совет, попробую